# Dependency injection of nest in babel particularly with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, babeljs, nestjs

I am following the guide of NestJs about Mongoose but with Babel and I'm facing an error trying to inject my schema. The code is pretty simple and it is just the same as the typescript examples but with babel.

This is my main module

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { EventModule } from './events/event-module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.MONGO_URI),
    EventModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This is the simplest schema example

```
import { Schema } from 'mongoose';

export const EventSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  description: Number,
});
```

The module event module:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

import { EventController } from "./event-controller";
import { EventService } from "./event-service";
import { EventSchema } from '../schemas/event-schema';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      { name: 'Event', schema: EventSchema }
    ])
  ],
  controllers: [EventController],
  providers: [
    EventService,
  ],
})
export class EventModule {}
```

And finally, the service where I want the schema to be used:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { EventSchema } from '../schemas/event-schema';

@Injectable()
export class EventService {
  @InjectModel(EventSchema) eventModel;
  async getAll() {
    return await this.eventModel.find().exec();
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I call `getAll` from the controller, it turns out that `eventModel` is undefined! No error is thrown at instantiation. The error thrown is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
    at EventService._callee$ (D:\.../event-service.js:9:34)
    at tryCatch (D:\...\node_modules\babel-polyfill\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:65:40)
```

Is it possible that in babel, the dependency injection works different for `nestjs`? How the `InjectModel` is supposed to work or how should it be used with babel?

Thank you very much in advance, any advice or tip is well appreciated and received

Regards

Comment: May try @Bind(InjectModel(EventSchema))

Comment: Does injecting into constructor work?

Comment: the contructor is not decorable, neither the arguments. The @Bind doesn't work with InjectModel

Comment: What do you mean by *constructor is not decorable*? Sorry if it is something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

There has a error:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { EventSchema } from '../schemas/event-schema';

@Injectable()
export class EventService {
  @InjectModel(EventSchema) eventModel;
  async getAll() {
    return await this.eventModel.find().exec();
  }
}
```

This line

```
@InjectModel(EventSchema) eventModel;
```

should be `@InjectModel('Event') eventModel`